# select copy and paste in terminal mac or ubuntu without using mouse

Tags: mac, ubuntu, terminal, copy-paste

Is there a way to move the cursor up into text output region, visually select text, copy and paste it, all without using the mouse.
I guess this is my scenario:
I would do a "find . -iname filename.extension" and there would be multiple files in different locations.  I want to vim that file, but I don't want to retype the whole file directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of starting an editor war ...

Emacs has a shell mode, allowing you to run a command and have all its output automatically be in an editable buffer.

I don't use vim myself, but from [this wikia entry](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window), it appears something similar is available for vim.

Comment: Oh very cool, That works really well when in vim.  Is there a way to do it without an editor though?