# How can I select text in the Mac OS X Terminal without a mouse (for copy and paste, emacs)

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, terminal, emacs

I am using Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and emacs 23.3.1. In the Terminal I can mark text with the mouse, copy it with <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and paste it with <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>. This is all I need and it works great, even within emacs. Which is important for me, since I'm still not very comfortable with it.

The only problem is, I have to use the mouse! How can I select the text with keyboard only? Is there really no solution?

[It seems like someone else had a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/295669/select-copy-and-paste-in-terminal-mac-or-ubuntu-without-using-mouse), though the unsatisfying answers (for me) suggest otherwise.

Comment: You could use Emacs, as suggested in that answer, or `screen` or `tmux`, which both provide a layer between the terminal and the programs running within, and support keyboard commands for navigating/searching the terminal contents.

Comment: @ChrisPage [Stop](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2967/is-it-okay-to-inform-users-to-stop-promoting-apple-se-when-a-question-is-fine-to/2968#2968) [it](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3723/apple-questions-to-imigrate-or-not-to-imigrate).

Comment: @DanielBeck Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ChrisPage My comment was referring to your deleted comment (moderators seem to agree) urging the user to ask this question on a different site.

Comment: @DanielBeck Is there some way for me to see the deleted comment so I can figure out exactly what this is about? Also, is there a way to send messages to users—say, you—without using this question’s comments to do it?

Comment: @ChrisPage deleted comments are only visible to diamond moderators. I don't remember the exact wording of your comment, but you suggested this question should be asked on apple.se, something that's frowned upon here. There is no private messaging or anything like that, either respond via comments or try chat. `@danielbeck` will work in the root access room of su chat even if I'm not there.

Comment: There was a feature in Mac OS X 10.4 to select text with the keyboard. http://www.macworld.com/article/1059321/termtext.html

Comment: Related later question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67926779/is-there-any-way-of-using-normal-keyboard-text-selection-with-a-terminal-on-maco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short of using some fancy scripting you can't select text without the mouse.  Alternatively you could use a terminal command like screen but then that isn't interacting with Mac clipboard.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ClarkGoble. I was afraid this would be the case. 
Isn't that something that thousands of OS X users want?

Comment: Your best alternative is to use iTerm2 instead of Terminal. It does allow mouse less copy. [link](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/features/mouseless)

Comment: Thank you so much ClarkGlobe!

iTerm2 seems to be very nice, and yes you can copy&paste text without the mouse, though only one line max and its a bit clumsy. Still better than nothing. Plus, I love full screen mode!

Still, it bugles my mind, that this is even an issue ...

Answer (score 3):

Use iterm2 instead, it has a special [Copy Mode](https://iterm2.com/documentation-copymode.html) that allows you to select text by keyboard. Press <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to enter and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit that mode. Use <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>v</kbd> to toggle selection

[image: Copy Mode]

[iTerm2 Mouseless Copy](https://kevinjalbert.com/iterm2-mouseless-copy/)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in the terminal. Firstly, go to the text you want to select, hold down the touch bar, and then use the finger to drag the text you want to select. Then, use <kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the text that you want to use.

Hope this will help.

Comment: this doesn't work